# Add unit test step on TFS build definition for .net project

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tfs

I have to run unit test which is using Nunit3 framework. I need to use nunit3-console.exe. Excute TFNMainTest object, dll name is SOMETHING.Tests.dll . This step i have to add in TFS build definition. How will i do this. Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: TFS Version 15.117.27024.0

Answer (score 0):

To execute NUnit test in TFS build, you should ensure that appropriate tests adapters are available to agents that will run the build.

The blog below describes clearly how to integrate NUnit Tests in TFS builds: [Running NUnit Tests in a TFS 2015 Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/03/16/running-nunit-tests-in-a-tfs-2015-build-vnext/):

1. Add Nuget Package for NUnit Test Adapter
2. Specify path of custom Test Adapter inside build definition

   - Copying adapters inside Visual Studio TestWindows folder
   - Specify Path to Custom Test Adapter with nunit packages

[image]